# Keyword searches broken on wiki.ros.org?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

It appears that keyword searches on wiki.ros.org are somewhat broken.  For example, if I search for **ar_kinect** which is an existing package with its [own wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_kinect), I get no results.

If I search for **arduino**, the [ros_arduino_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_arduino_bridge) package does not show up in the results and if I search directly for **ros_arduino_bridge**, I get only one hit to the [geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/) wiki page which doesn't even make sense as ros_arduino_bridge does not depend directly on this package.

Some searches work OK but there are many like the ones above.

Thanks,
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88596/keyword-searches-broken-on-wiki.ros.org?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-08**:
@Dirk Thomas any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the moinmoin wiki has exceed its "recommended" page limit by far the search is not using the moinmoin specific search at all. Instead it used Google search. So there is no "keyword" search but just "plain text" search.

I don't know why the previously integrated Google search was so bad but I guess it was not updated correctly during the transition to the new hosting. Anyway a normal google search seems to bring up the expected results (e.g. http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ar_kinect+site%3Awiki.ros.org).

I created a new Google custom search profile. Now the results of the search should be more appealing.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-10-08**:
Awesome--works great now.  Many thanks!